# Managing JMS Message Containers on Application Startup and Shutdown

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, wicket, apache-zookeeper

Currently, we have four JMS listener containers that are started during the application start. They all connect through Apache ZooKeeper and are manually started. This becomes problematic when a connection to ZooKeeper cannot be established. The (Wicket) application cannot start, even though it is not necessary for the JMS listeners be active to use the application. They simply need to listen to messages in the background, save them and a cron job will process them in batches.

**Goals**:

1. Allow the application to start and not be prevented by the message containers not being able to connect.
2. After the application starts, start the message listeners.
3. If the connection to one or any of the message listeners goes down, it should attempt to automatically reconnect.
4. On application shutdown (such as the Tomcat being shutdown), the application should stop the message listeners and the cron job that processes the saved messages.
5. Make all of this testable (as in, be able to write integration tests for this setup).

**Current Setup**:

1. Spring Boot 1.5.6
2. Apache ZooKeeper 3.4.6
3. Apache ActiveMQ 5.7
4. Wicket 7.7.0

**Work done so far**:

1. Define a class that implements `ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>`.
2. Setting the `autoStart` property of the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` to false and start each container in the `onApplicationEvent` in a separate thread.

**Questions**:

1. Is it necessary to start each message container in its own thread? This seems to be overkill, but the way the "start" process works is that the DefaultMessageListenerContainer is built for that listener and then it is started. There is a UI component that a user can use to start/stop the message listeners if need be, and if these are started sequentially in one thread, then the latter three message containers could be null if the first one has yet to connect on startup.
2. How do I accomplish goals 4 and 5?

Of course, any commments on whether I am on the right track would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not start them in a custom thread then the whole application cannot be fully started. It is not just Wicket, but the Servlet container won't change the application state from STARTING to STARTED due to the blocking request to ZooKeeper.

Another option is to use a non-blocking request to ZooKeeper but this is done by the JMS client (ActiveMQ), so you need to check whether this is supported in their docs (both ActiveMQ and ZooKeeper). I haven't used those in several years, so I cannot help you more.

Comment: Hello @martin-g, thank you for taking a look at my question. I still have a few open questions. From what it appears, if I do not start each of them in a separate thread, then if one cannot connect, then the subsequent containers will wait until the first connects. But how does one control these threads? When I shutdown the application now, the threads stay open after the Spring context has been destroyed, so point 4 has yet to be fulfilled. Point 5 is where I am still quite unsure.

Comment: It depends how you have started them. I prefer using ExecutorService. You can shut it down in Servlet Filter#destroy(), Wicket Application#onDestroy(), Spring onEvent(ApplicationStopped), etc.

Comment: This was solved by starting each of the listeners in a separate thread. A graceful shutdown was more or less achieved using an ApplicationListener. I say more or less since there was one edge case that was not easy to solve, and that was when the application started, but the listeners never connected. The application would hang until the grace period elapsed and then it was forcibly shut down. In any case, thank you, @martin-g.